# Ckeditor Simply add break

Tags: php, javascript, html, web, ckeditor

For my Ckeditor text box, I need a line break after a certain amount of characters. The site I manage converts this rich text using tcpdf to generate over a pdf. Long story short, the box lets them type to much in and it carries over with a break at the wrong point from what they can see. So my solution is to shrink the box to the appropriate size, and so that it adds the break at the appropriate spot, or if there is a forcible way to make it put a line break in after a certain amount of text is entered that would be very helpful.

Comment: editing the text box size won't solve my issue, figured out how to do that. Need to be able to add a newline after a certain amount of characters.

Comment: It is not possible. HTML does not provide such a feature.

Comment: Ckeditor has nothing to do with the HTML side of things in base to my question. It is built with javascript. I came up with a simpler solution for usability, because a new line wouldn't have solved my issue either. Needless to say, you are wrong in saying that a script couldn't be written to do this, and or that Ckeditor couldn't be edited to do what I was asking. Please be more constructive and informed next time.

Comment: I am actually a CKEditor core developer and I know what is possible using `contenteditable` and what is not. CKEditor is indeed written in JavaScript, but as a core of editing feature it uses HTML and its editing capabilities based on `contenteditable` attribute. So as you're not able to wrap text after a certain amount of characters in HTML+CSS (unless you set monospace font and correctly defined width of a box) you're not able to achieve this in `contenteditable` without very (really - **very**) complex JS helper.

Comment: Download there base package and alter the CS for them if you need minor changes. They have an api that can show you what to alter, and a list of massive options to set with the class you want to use or styles you want. That's what helped me all that time ago.